# How many characters in 'Solo: A Star Wars Story' also appear in other Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

I know Han Solo, Chewbacca, and Lando Calrissian reappeared in the Original Trilogy, has anyone else appeared in both Solo:ASWS and other current (Disney) Star Wars Canon?

Comment: This question isn't too broad. The list of characters is absolute, even if it is a long list.

Comment: Theres also the list of actors that appeared in other Star Wars movies, which will be different from the list of characters.

Comment: Quick search on IMDb gives a list of every character (both major and minor roles). Et voila: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3778644/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast. Match these with the Original trilogy cast; you will get your answer.

Comment: @Shreedhar there exist more than just 3 films.

Comment: @Verdan actually I didn't someone edited my question to make it about OT :[ I've since edited it again to be as inclusive as I intended.

Comment: I apologise @JaredK that was indeed my fault. I tried to edit to make the question a bit clearer but neglected to re-state that you were indeed looking for any films, not just the OT (as my answer shows I'd understood that initially).

Comment: Well, the random edit made it all confusing.. Jared, buddy, you're looking for all movies and not just the OT right. Perfect. more clear now

Comment: no worries @Edlothiad and great answer :)

Comment: Since the additional/upcoming canon includes several novelisations of the film, the answers is "yes, all of them".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Below is a list of characters that have appeared in other films and the films they've appeared in.

Format:
*The character - Films/TV Shows*

Information for films characters have appeared in is based on the information from [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story#app_characters) on character appearances for Solo.
<sub>A guide to film acronyms can be found at the bottom.</sub>

- Han Solo - ANH, ESB, RotJ, TFA, SW:FoD
- Chewbacca - SW:TCW, RotS, ANH, ESB, RotJ, TFA, TLJ, SW:FoD
- Lando Calrissian - SW:Reb, ESB, RotJ
- Darth Maul - TPM, SW:TCW, SW:Reb
- Qi'Ra - SW:FoD
- Tam Posla - RO
- Weazel - TPM (First identified in Solo, credits to [@Neow](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/43246/neow))
- Aurra Sing<sup>†</sup> - TPM, SW:TCW
- Bossk<sup>†</sup> - SW:TCW, ESB, RotJ

Darth Maul and Tam Posla are the only characters who have appeared in other films that wasn't on your original list.

Qi'Ra's first appearance is credited as being for Solo. However the episode of Forces of Destiny she features in was released on the same day as the film (25th May 2018)

<sup>†</sup>Mentioned only in *Solo: A Star Wars Story*

---

**Acronym Guide**

TPM - *The Phantom Menace*
RotS - *Revenge of the Sith*
ANH - *A New Hope*
ESB - *Empire Strikes Back*
RotJ - *Return of the Jedi*
TFA - *The Force Awakens*
TLJ - *The Last Jedi*
RO - *Rogue One*
SW:TCW - *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*
SW:Reb - *Star Wars: Rebels*
SW:FoD - *Star Wars: Forces of Destiny*

Comment: In addition, Warwick Davis plays a character named Weazel who appeared in TPM and Solo : http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Weazel

Comment: I may be mistaken (just saw it once, and it is brief) but I wonder if the guy commanding the robot's fight arena isn't supposed to become the angry guy with the "punched in nose" (which happens in Solo, if it turns out to be true) that angrily talk to the heroes when they enter the Cantina? [http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cornelius_Evazan , according to wikia?]. I was really thinking this while watching Solo, but someone may need to have a look at ANH's scene and that Solo scene again to confirm/rebute it

Comment: @OlivierDulac, no that character is called [Ralakili](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ralakili)

Comment: Benthic or Edrio Two-Tubes (from Rogue One) may have been one of the Cloud-Riders, but it might just be an individual from the same species.

Comment: I’m unsure what you’re on about, @MarathontoMay. But according to wookiepedia, the cloud riders weren’t in Solo. However neither Benthic or Edrio appear in Solo

Comment: Aurra Sing appeared in TPM too :)
We can see her in the Boonta Eve :
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurra_Sing

Comment: @iammg thanks I totally missed that!

Comment: Han Solo and Chewbacca appeared in Forces of Destiny as well.

Comment: There likely were more that appeared in FoD that first appeared in Solo, but thanks, added @Rogue

Comment: Edited to spoiler tag major spoiler / reveal

Comment: @NKCampbell this is an 6 year old reveal. Please don't break the formatting of my answer for something that's a non-issue.

Comment: I disagree that it's a non-issue to reveal that character is in the new movie. It's kinder to not spoil that info at the moment. Your answer formatting was fine and it's not like it is against the rules to edit. Shrug. Sorry if you were offended

Comment: I wasn't offended, just chose to present my answer in a certain way, and feel this is a real non-issue to both the plot or the overall story.

Answer (score -3):

Since L3-37 has been "uploaded" to the Millenium Falcon, I would argue that she is in all the movies in which the Millenium Falcon appears : ANH, ESB, RotJ, TFA, TLJ.

Comment: The character, however, hadn't existed before the prequel novel to Solo, and therefore wasn't in the films.