# Is there an alternate reality/universe female version of Thanos?

Tags: marvel, comics, thanos

I recently came across some Thanos fan-art depicting the mad-Titan as a female (*image below*). This got me thinking, is there an alternate version of Thanos who is female?

[image: Female Thanos by NEOARTCORE]

Comment: As per your comment [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188556/how-many-characters-in-solo-a-star-wars-story-also-appear-in-other-star-wars/188558#comment513160_188556) I googled "female thanos". Et voila, the first hit I was linked to was [this page](https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-thanos-comics-never-movies/) which told me that he created a female version of himself called Terraxia, who first featured in Infinty Gauntlet #3. This fan-art however was just Thanos using the IG to give himself a [gender change](https://neoartcore.deviantart.com/art/Thanos-742915266).

Comment: That is creepy.

Answer (score 8):

## [Terraxia (Earth-616)](http://marvel.com/universe/Terraxia)

The linked Marvel page describes Thanos bringing her into existence as follows.

> When Death turned her back on Thanos while he was in possession of the Infinity Gauntlet, Thanos created a new partner and equal who he named Terraxia. He created Terraxia in his likeness but still left her with some frailties.

She was shown to be created by Thanos in *Infinity Gauntlet #3*.

[image: Infinity Gauntlet #3, Terraxia's creation]

She is later killed in *Infinity Gauntlet #5* by Nebula.

[image: Infinity Gauntlet #5, Terraxia's death]

---

## Terraxia (Earth-18451)

She briefly shows up in *What If...? #49* but only for the Silver Surfer to put her back into none existence.

[image: What If...? #49]

---

Lastly, although I figure you may already know this the image you link is from Deviant Art user "NeoArtCorE" and a fan art suggesting Thanos has used the Infinity Gauntlet for gender changes.

> Fanart : Thanos from Avengers: Infinity War
>
> No spoilers thread!! Infinity Gauntlet, Infinity Power for gender changes
>
> Thanosaaa :3
>
> <sup>[Deviant Art, NeoArtCorE, Thanos](https://neoartcore.deviantart.com/art/Thanos-742915266)</sup>

Comment: I excluded her. She's invented as his perfect consort, not his female alternate.

Comment: @Valorum She's created in his likeness not as another Titan which suggests she is a version of him.

Comment: Terraxia was created by Thanos to make Lady death jealous,. She wasn’t a *Thanos*.. she was merely kinda rebound gal for him.. i too found terraxia before asking the question. But I don’t know if she counts.. however, if there’s none; then this might be the closest I can get to an answer.

Comment: @Shreedhar As I explained to Richard she appears to be a female version of Thanos created by Thanos (but with the power levels dropped). However, if you found her before you posted the question you should really add it into the question itself (before posting, adding it now would invalidate my answer) along with why you're ruling her out etc.