# Which Fantastic Beasts characters were mentioned in earlier Harry Potter movies?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

Has any Fantastic Beasts character ever been mentioned in the Harry Potter movies? (Besides Newt, the Dumbledores and Grindelwald)

Comment: Lots! It'll probably be a long list. Nicholas Flamel comes to mind immediately.

Comment: This question is on topic. It's not [an infinite list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2639/82909) and it may not be as long as you think. See [How many characters in 'Solo: A Star Wars Story' also appear in other Star Wars canon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188556/82909) for comparison.

Comment: Minerva McGonagall, Nagini, Nicholas Flamel and the four you've already mentioned.

Comment: Merlin gets mentioned in both (or at least his beard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Characters You Didn't Mention

- **Nagini** (a Maledictus in Fantastic Beasts -- a snake in Harry Potter)
- **Nicolas Flamel** (creator of the sorcerer's stone in both, but only appears as a name in Harry Potter)
- **Minerva McGonagall** (student in Fantastic Beasts -- Professor at Hogwarts in Harry Potter)

### Ones That You Mentioned

- **Albus Dumbledore** (teaches Defense Against Dark Arts in Fantastic Beasts -- Headmaster of Hogwarts in Harry Potter)
- **Aberforth Dumbledore** (younger brother of Albus, tavern keeper of the Hog's Head in Hogsmeade)
- **Arianna Dumbledore** (younger sister of Albus and Aberforth -- dead in both)
- **Gellert Grindelwald** (1st place Dark wizard in Fantastic beasts -- 2nd place Dark wizard in Harry Potter )
- **Newt Scamander** (one of the main characters going against Grindelwald in Fantastic Beasts -- author of Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them in Harry Potter)

Comment: Arianna is a good catch, although she's mentioned as a dead character.

Answer (score 3):

Taking into account all three *Fantastic Beasts* films, 7 of the named characters pre-exist the films;

### Books

- **Newt Scamander** - First mentioned in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*
- **Prof. Albus Dumbledore** - First mentioned in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*
- **Prof. Minerva McGonagoll** - First mentioned in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*
- **Gellert Grindelwald** - First mentioned in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*
- **Nicholas Flamel** - First mentioned in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*
- **Aberforth Dumbledore** - First mentioned in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*
- **Nagini** - First mentioned in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*

### Films

- **Newt**

Newt doesn't appear in the respective film of the same name, but he does makes a cameo appearance in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* on the Marauder's Map.

> [image]

- **Prof. Dumbledore, McGonagoll, Grindlewald, Flamel**

These characters are mentioned by name in the opening acts of the first film

> **Dumbledore:** *I should have known that you would be here...**Professor McGonagall.***

> **Ron:** *'**Dumbledore** is particularly famous for his defeat of the
> Dark" Wizard **Grindelwald** in 1945–'*
>
> **Harry:** *Go on.*
>
> **Ron:** *'-for his discovery of the 12 uses of Dragon Blood, and his work
> on alchemy with his partner **Nicolas Flamel**!'*
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*</sup></sub>

- **Aberforth**

Dumbledore's brother doesn't get a mention in the films until *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* where he is shown in a [group picture](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Aberforth_Dumbledore?file=Order_of_the_Phoenix.png) of the titular order.

- **Nagini**

Seen in the opening scene of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

> 

Comment: Wait where did Nagini show up in Fantastic Beasts?

Comment: Oh wow!!! She was the lady that transformed into the snake...did they call her by name? Now I have to rewatch.

Comment: @MichaelBrown - Credence calls her by name.